# App engine standard firewall rule ignored when using a browser but not when using curl

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, firewall

I am running into a peculiar issue when adding my IP address to an app engine standard firewall.

1) I go https://www.whatismyip.com/ -> 1.2.3.4 (fake ofcourse)
2) I add this rule to the app engine firewall -> 4000 Allow 1.2.3.4 allow-home-network
3) I go to Google chrome and type in the address bar http://project-id.appspot.com/ -> 403 access denied
4) I do a curl curl --location --request GET 'http://project-id.appspot.com/' -> I get a 200 response, so it is not blocked

I posted this issue with google and recorded a HAR and they said that my remote IP address was different than the one that https://www.whatismyip.com/ gave me.

So instead of it being a GCP problem I was wondering if it has something to do with my machine / ethernet setup. Colleagues of mine are able to connect when I add their IP to the app engine firewall rules.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get my access working?

I have no VPN or other proxy plugins installed in my google chrome. Also firefox and edge show the same behavior.

Hope someone can help me because this is an annoying problem.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: I understand that you can access through curl but not through the browser. is this consistent or sometimes you can access through the browser? also check your ip again but by trying in Google Search "whatsmyip" you will get a first result as your ip. compare it with the one from whatmyip.com .

Comment: This is consistent behavior. Curl always works, browser never works. whatsmyip in google search is the same result as whatsmyip.com

Comment: did you try on another computer in your network?